# Set up shortcut for object interaction mode

Tags: shortcut

Does anyone know how to create a shortcut that will make this menu appear?

[image]

I'm guessing I need to use wm.context_menu_enum. And I'm hoping I just need the appropriate info to put into the 'Context Attributes' field. Can anyone provide that?

And how would I be able to figure that out for myself, so I can solve future problems?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, the `TAB` hotkey will toggle between *object* and *edit* modes.

As of **Blender 2.8**, `CTRL+TAB` will display a Pie menu like in Ariso's answer; but without the need of an addon.

---

You can also set **your own shortcuts** for object interaction modes.

1. Go to *Edit > User Preferences*
2. Click the *Input* tab.
3. Expand *3D view* > *Object non modal*
4. Click *Add New* and expand the created shortcut to edit it.

For the identifier, type `object.mode_set`.
This will bring a new box that will allow you to set a specific mode.

Example of custom setup where hotkeys `F1`, `F2` and `F3` are respectively mapped to the *object*, *edit* and *draw* mode.

[image]

Comment: I have a Razer Naga mouse, in which I mapped the 1-12 buttons to CTRL+ALT+F[number] shortcuts when using Blender, then in Blender I created custom shortcuts that use the CTRL+ALT+F[numbers], where the 1-3 are to jump to Object, Edit and Pose mode instantly and your answer worked perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the "Pie menu's" addon? It comes by default in Blender so you maybe have it already, it allows you to spawn a wheel of menus which you can select with a click or by hovering your mouse in the desired option.

[image]
[image]

It also allows to create wheels for other menus in the 3D viewport like animation, 3D cursor, set origin menu, etc.
You can also switch to these menu's while the wheel is active by pressing any of the assignated numbers next to the options.

Hope this works.

Comment: Thanks! I prefer this alternative method and will use it, but hopefully we can still get the direct answer.